# Запись в файл из объекта класса

Tags: файлы, c++builder, запись

Хочу записать в файл информацию из класса, но записывается непонятно что (МґKњґK„ґKd). Пробовал использовать и fwrite и fprintf.

```
Cast film1;
    film1.Input("q", "w", "e", 100);
    FILE *f1;
        if(!(f1 = fopen("film1.txt","a+"))){
            ShowMessage("Error!");
            return;
        }
    fprintf(f1,(char*)&film1);
    fclose (f1);
```

Класс:

```
class Cast
{
private:
    String genre, role, director;
    int views;
public:
    Cast();
    Input(String, String, String, int);
};

Cast::Cast(){
    genre = role = director = views = NULL;
}

Cast::Input(String a, String b, String c, int d){
    genre = a;
    role = b;
    director = c;
    views = d;
}
```

Выходной файл должен иметь вид:
"q
w
e
100"

Comment: А вы откройте в dump  окне (Ctrl+Alt+C) ваш film 1 и посмотрите чему равны байты в дампе. Они совпадут. Для записи классов в файл, нужно понимать что ссылки записывать безсмысленно. Вам нужно сделать "сериализацию" или "кодирование" класса в такие байты, что б можно было прочесть.

Comment: Если вы не хотите делать "сериализацию", - не используйте указатели (или ссылки - так ошибочно называют указатели). Ваше q w e должно быть обьявлено как `q char[10];` или `q char;` и звёздочек `*` быть не должно в обьявлении класса.

Comment: И вторая ошибка, а с чего вы взяли что класс хранится в формате ASCII-Z? Класс не хранится в этом формате. Если же вы хотите хранить данные в "текстовом" виде, то делайте функцию преобразования класса в текст, или как вариант сложнее, сделайте explicit-оператор, если ф-ция вам не нравится. Как вариант 3 - обьявите **первое поле** класса, как `char[100]` например, и храните там ascii-z, тогда (char*)&film1 - даст ASCII-z.

Comment: Вопрос ответа не имеет потому что 1. Не приведено содержимое класса Cast, 2. Не показано каким должен быть выходной файл.

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил описание класса и пример выходного файла

Comment: Такой класс никогда не даст такой файл.

Comment: @nick_n_a что и где тогда нужно исправить?

Comment: Вам нужно писать вручную функцию "сериализации", которая 1. вернёт "q w e 100". Или 2 - в буфер запишет "q w e 100", а буфер скинет в файл.

Comment: Есть и проще выход - сделать вычисления на лету.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

Comment: Будет выражение `fprintf(f1,"%s %s %s %i\n",  film1.genre.c_str() ,` и т д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй самый простой вариант, учитывая, что файл **текстовый**, это

```
fprintf(f1,"%s %s %s %i\n", film1.genre.c_str(), film1.role.c_str(), film1.director.c_str(), film1.views);
```

`с_str()` - переводит обьект String в формат ASCII-Z который нужен ф-ции [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).

Но... так как у нас всётаки обьекто-ориентированое програмирование, лучше сделать это ф-цией класса, т.е. где-то так

```
class Cast
{
 public:
    void Save(FILE * f1){
      fprintf(f1,"%s %s %s %i\n", genre.c_str(), role.c_str(), director.c_str(),views);
      }
```

Добавлю, что читать будет это сложнее. Прийдётся разбить по-пробелу. Если в одном из стрингов хранятся пробелы, можно перевести в csv при условии что ";" не занята.  `fprintf(f1,"%s;%s;%s;%i\n"`

---

Теперь о "Запись в файл из объекта класса". Запись `fprintf(f1,(char*)&film1);` не совсем верная. Но её "оживить" можно, если вам нужен **двоичный** файл, где каждый байт будет занимать конкретное место.  Тогда можно будет вычитывать все данные о файле в одно действие, но пострадает читабельность файла. Что бы с++ сделал "читабельный" вид, нужно чётко задать структуру и использовать типы без указателей, например так:

```
 class Cast{
    char genre[8],   // 000: 71 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   q 
         role[8],    // 008: 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   w
         director[8];// 010: 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   e
       int views;    // 018: 64 00 00 00               d

      Input(char*, char*, char*, int);
   }

 Cast::Input(char* a, char* b, char* c, int d){
   strcpy(genre, a); // Грубо, нужно ещё проверить длинну строк strlen
   strcpy(role, b);
   strcpy(director, c);
   views = d;
}
```

Тогда это можно записывать в одно действие: `fwrite ( &film1, 1, sizeof(Cast), f1 );`, а потом можно прочесть в одно действие вот так `fread( &film1, 1, sizeof(Cast), f1 );` - получится размер одного "блока" 28 байт (как в коментариях). Если структура в будущем изменится - файлы "старой" версии перестанут читаться, поэтому важно сразу продумать структуру. Если нужно быстро организовать запись и чтение - можно так делать. Записывать/читать можно так же несколько элементов сразу используя массив. Если этот способ вам понравился, рекомендую ознакомится с выравниванием памяти  [хабр](http://habr.com/post/142662/), [пример1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754240/always-same-effect-of-pragma-pack16-and-pragma-pack8?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Остаётся добавить, что для сложных классов нужно или использовать библиотеки сериализации, или писать доп-функции которые будут переводить в текстовый или двоичный вид. Ссылки нужно заменять либо на относительные (что бы можно было вычислить реальный адрес) либо на номер в массиве. Строки делать или фиксированой длинны, как во втором примере выше, либо делать длинна_строки + строка, либо делать ASCII-z (в чисом виде ASCII-z редко используется). Если файл состоит из "блоков" с раздельной информацией - часто указывают размер блока.

Comment: спасибо большое вам за ответ, правда я не совсем понял, как мы перевели в "человеческий" язык:)

Comment: Почитайте ф-цию fprintf - она переводит числа в текст, и обьеденяет ascii-z строки.